# Does anyone know what the name Peter translates to in Egyptian?

Tags: names, egyptian

**Peter**

I need to find out what the name Peter translates to in Egyptian.

Comment: Why would a name that was only coined in the New Testament show up in pre-Roman Egypt? Egypt was annexed in 30 BC.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I have updated the question, because in heindsight the name after death will be equally as good.

Comment: Why do you **need* to find this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Peter" is originally a Greek name, popularized by the spread of Christianity. And the form of the Egyptian language spoken when Christianity became widespread is generally referred to as "Coptic" rather than "Egyptian" (though linguistically it's a descendant of the language called "Egyptian").

So in Coptic, the name is ⲡⲉⲧⲣⲟⲥ (*Petros*), a straightforward adaptation of Greek Πέτρος (*Pétros*).

Alternately, if you're asking about modern-day Egypt, you'll want the Arabic: بُطْرُس (*Buṭrus*), again a straightforward adaptation of the Greek.

Comment: I don't see why it should be a comment. Perfectly good answer. Would vote up but dont have points. Was not the answer i wanted though. Was hoping it would be Ptah.